# Reading more than one dataframe from a function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I wrote these codes to read Datastes:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

def load_coordinates(structure,segments:None):
       
    filedir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent / "data" / structure
    filepath = filedir / f"coordinates_{structure}.csv"
    return pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")
    if segments:
        return df.loc[df.segment.isin(segments)].reset_index(drop=True)
    else:
        return df
```

```
def load_population(structure,segments:None):
    
    filedir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent / "data" / structure
    filepath = filedir / f"population_{structure}.csv"
    return pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")
    return df.loc[df.segment.isin(segments)].reset_index(drop=True)
    else:
        return df
```

```
def load_ambul_praxen(structure,segments=None):
  
    filedir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent / "data" / structure
    filepath = filedir / f"ambul_praxen_{structure}.csv"
    return pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";").drop(columns=["planet"])
    return df.loc[df.segment.isin(segments)].reset_index(drop=True)
    else:
        return df
```

```
def load_docs_matrix(structure, docs_selection, sum_up_vo):
    
    filedir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent / "data" / structure
    filepath = filedir / f"docs_matrix_{structure}.csv"
    return pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")

    selected_cols = ["segment"] + docs_selection
    df = df.loc[:, selected_cols]
    if sum_up_vo:
        df["vo"] = df[docs_selection].sum(axis=1)
        df = df.drop(columns=docs_selection)

    return df
```

```
def load_weights(structure, request, segments=None, docs_selection=None, sum_up_vo=None):
    if request == "population":
        return load_population(structure)
    elif request == "ambul_praxen":
        return load_ambul_praxen(structure)
    else:
        return load_docs_matrix(structure)
```

```
def load_data(structure, request, segments=None, docs_selection=None, 
       sum_up_vo=None):
coordinates = load_coordinates(structure)
weights = load_weights(structure, request, segments, docs_selection, sum_up_vo)

return coordinates.merge(weights, on="segment", how="inner")
```

before calling the function, I want to add this:

```
if segments:
        return df.loc[df.segment.isin(segments)].reset_index(drop=True)
    else:
        return df
```

to `def load_docs_matrix` function

```
I called the function like this:

request = "ambul_praxen"
structure = "1868"

load_data(structure,request,
          load_coordinates,
          load_ambul_praxen,
          load population,
          load_weights)
```

What I want to achieve is put all the datasets in one dataframe with the `load data function`.after calling the function , I got an error that I gave 7 arguments but 5 is expected.I tried to adjust the arguments but it seems not to work.

Any idea on how I could solve this?

Comment: It isn't very clear what the intended output is, can you clarify?

Comment: @ fbence, I want to load the full dataset from the model with the last function and call it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but if you just want to call these reading dataframe's functions, just:

```
def load_data(input_df, structure, request):
    coordinates = load_coordinates(structure)
    population = load_population(structure)
    ambul_praxen = load_ambul_praxen(structure)
    docs_matrix = load_docs_matrix(structure)
    weighs = load_weights(structure,request)

    #Maybe concatenate them horizontally?
    return pd.concat([coordinates,population,ambul_praxen,docs_matrix,weighs],axis=1)
```

Or just return them one by one...